# Booting into Ubuntu after booting into Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 Mate edition perfectly fine. I've created a swap, root, home partition and I've used the 100MB partition that Windows create as the efi partition.

Everything seems to work fine, except the moment I boot into windows. For some reason my computer doesn't seem to boot into grub anymore, but straight into Windows.

I've look into my uefi bios to look for the boot order. at first it said Ubuntu, but now it says Windows Boot Manager.

I am clueless at the moment, maybe you guys could help me.

Answer (score 2):

Boot into Windows - **disable** hibernation and Fast Boot.
Open **command prompt as administrator** and execute:

```
powercfg /h off
```

In case you installed Windows 8 or 10 in EFI mode:
Open **Windows Control Panel** -> **Energy Settings**.
Enable **show hidden settings** - uncheck **Fast Boot**.
**Shutdown** the machine completely, do NOT reboot.
Boot into BIOS - select Ubuntu to be the default OS.